# Craft CMS on LEMP Stack (mcrypt not detected)

Tags: mcrypt

I have a LEMP droplet on digitalocean that I am trying to get working with Craft CMS. 
Strangely it does not seem to play nice with NGINX. Or maybe it's just me.

After installation I am receiving the below message;
[image: Screenshot]

I do have php5-mcrypt installed and it appears in phpinfo()

[image: phpinfo() screenshot]

Can anyone help? Thanks.

-- NGINX config for craft (craft.conf)

```
server {
  listen   80;

  root /var/www/public;
  index index.php index.html index.htm;

  server_name ger1-riverrun.mydomain.com;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrites;
  }

  location @rewrites {
    rewrite ^(.*) /index.php?p=$1 last;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
  }

  error_page 404 /index.php;

}
```

Comment: Are you on Ubuntu? [This](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/enable-mcrypt-extension-in-nginx) might be useful? Any config change always do a ``service nginx restart && php5-fpm restart`` to make sure everything gets reloaded.

Comment: Yes, ubuntu 14. Wow, I feel foolish now, restart of php5-fpm fixed it! thanks

Answer (score 1):

RitterKnights solution worked! I hadnt restarted php5-fpm.